# How to solve uncaptured payment "Stripe Payments with Caldera Forms"

Tags: stripe, payment, caldera-forms

my problem is when I pay a contribution using Stripe and Caldera forms, i receive in Stripe account the payment is not captured.

I have tried paying the contribution directly without using the caldera forms and it works.

Someone had the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by using cf-civicrm developer version from github rather than the version proposed by Wordpress.
To understand more you can see this Post : https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm/issues/185